# How to list all content types by number?

Tags: 10

I have a website with many content types and my problem is that counting the number of content types unlisted by numbers might be hard or confusing because of the high amount of content types.

When in `/admin/structure/types` the following JavaScript codes may somewhat help.

#### JavaScript 1

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('tr').length -1); 
// -1 to reduce table heading;
```

> **50** (just an example number)

### JavaScript 2

```js
const allTableRowsExceptTableHeading = document.querySelectorAll('tr.odd, tr.even');

allTableRowsExceptTableHeading.forEach((element) => {
    const newCell = document.createElement('td');
    // This variable must be here inside the function because...
        // For each table row we work on, we create and add a table cell...

    element.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', newCell);

    newCell.innerHTML = '<span class="numberCell">A</span>';
    newCell.style.display = 'table-cell';
    newCell.style.width = 'maxContent';
    newCell.style.textAlign = 'center';
    newCell.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    // These HTML-CSS directives must be here inside the function because...
        // For each table row we work on, we create and add these new HTML-CSS directives...
});

let baseNumber = 1;
document.querySelectorAll('.numberCell').forEach((element)=>{
    element.innerHTML = `<span>${baseNumber++}</span>`;
});
```

### My question

How to list all content types by number, especially backendly instead frontendly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community bot, done.

Answer (score 0):

In backend PHP add your own list builder to the content type aka node type:

*mymodule.module*

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_type_alter().
 */
function mymodule_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
  $entity_types['node_type']->setHandlerClass('list_builder', 'Drupal\mymodule\MyNodeTypeListBuilder');
}
```

*/src/MyNodeTypeListBuilder.php*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\node\NodeTypeListBuilder;

class MyNodeTypeListBuilder extends NodeTypeListBuilder {

  protected $number = 1;

  public function buildHeader() {
    $header['number'] = t('Number');
    return $header + parent::buildHeader();
  }

  public function buildRow(EntityInterface $entity) {
    $row['number'] = $this->number++;
    return $row + parent::buildRow($entity);
  }

}
```

This answers the second javascript snippet, the question title and the last **my question**. If the first javascript snippet is not only for debugging but should also be included in the entity list then override render() as well:

```
  public function render() {
    $build = parent::render();
    $this->number--;
    $build['total'] = ['#markup' => "<p>Total: $this->number<p/>"];
    return $build;
  }
```

If you want to have all content types on one page add

```
  protected $limit = FALSE;
```

to the class to disable the pager.